# Laplace transform of a signal multiplied to a time function

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, control-theory

Laplace transform of multiplication of two time functions can be calculated easily using standard formulae. But I have a problem in which signal $x(t)$ is multiplied to a time function. I have to do control analysis of the problem.
[Feedback loop diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuAy4.png)

Here, $z(t)=cos(\Omega t) x(t)$.

For control analysis, I need to get relationship between $Z(s)$ and $X(s)$.

As per defination of Laplace transform,  $X(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-s t} dt$, it can be derived

$Z(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x(t) e^{j \Omega t} e^{-s t} dt = X(s-j \Omega)$
But, this relationship cannot be used for control analysis like root locus and many other things.

> Can someone help me for getting relationship between $X(s)$ and $Z(s)$? How can convolution theorem be used in this regard?

Comment: Is $cos(x) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{jx}-e^{-jx})$ useful?

Comment: Thats I have tried.I will get 0.5 (X(s+j Omega) + X(s-j Omega)).  But, I dont know how I can get X(s) form which is required for further analysis.

Answer (score -1):

Multiplication in the time-domain corresponds to convolution in the Laplace domain.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But how it can be implemented to get the relationship between Z(s) and X(s).